Windows storage spaces not showing drives
I am trying to create a Raid 5; it should be trivial.
Three Toshiba 2TB external drives through a USB Hub, one SSD external.
The OS is Windows 11 Home.
Storage spaces show only the SSD when try to Create a new pool.
I cannot find raid support in the BIOS, but since storage spaces finds the SSD the problem seems to be with the drives.  Perhaps the SATA controller on two machines.
Disk management New Raid 5 volume is greyed out.
I have tried NTFS and FAT on the external drives.
I tried plugging in directly to the PC to get storage spaces to see the drive.
I tried storage spaces on a laptop with one of the drives.

RAID 5 obviously requires more than one disk, I even think, it requires more than 4 disks. Are you able to create a Storage Space of any configuration with the same external + internal ssd? I suspect the problem is the disks are external instead of internal. Storage Spaces is a software RAID you don’t want to enable RAID support in the firmware that’s for something completely different than what your doing

While it is STRONGLY recommended that you not build an array using external drives, it IS possible. Note that there are good reasons why it is STRONGLY recommended that you not do this.
